# How to use a parameter from a follow-up intent within the Inline Editor in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm using the DialogFlow Inline Editor and I need to be able to provide different responses based on the specific values of a parameter within a follow up intent.

Via the UI, I am able to build a follow up intent and refer to an entity in the previous intent, but I can't set up logic based on specific values of that entity, which is why i need to be able to do this via the Online Editor.

Can someone show me an example of how to use an entity within a follow up intent via the Online Editor?

So far, I am able to output a context within a function (function 1 below), but i am unable to use an entity that was provided by the user within function 1 in a function 2 that uses a follow-up intent.

```
    //function 1:
    function fruit(agent) {
        const fruit = agent.parameters.FruitValue
        agent.add(`what fruit do you like`)
        agent.setContext({ name: 'cherries-followup', lifespan: 2, parameters: {FruitValue: fruit}})}

    //function 2:
function details(agent) {
    const context = agent.getContext('cherries-followup');
    const fruit = context.parameters.FruitValue;
    agent.add(`Good to know you like ${fruit}!`);
}

    intentMap.set('CherriesIntent', fruit);
    intentMap.set('CherriesDetailIntent', details);
```

Picture of what I did via the UI which i would like to replicate in the Online Editor
[image: Picture of what I did via the UI which i would like to replicate in the Online Editor]

---

Update (Solved):

I have now rewritten the code to be in line with the DF post (so that it is easier to debug: https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/integrate-services)

```
    function languageHandler(agent) {
        const language_spoken = agent.parameters.language;
         {agent.add(`Wow! Where did you learn ${language_spoken} and for how long?`);
            agent.setContext({
                  name: 'languages-followup',
                  lifespan: 2,
                  parameters:{languages: language_spoken}
                });
        } 
        }

    function languageCustomHandler(agent) {
        const context = agent.getContext('languages-followup');
        //const allContexts = agent.contexts; // [{ name: 'languages-followup', ...}]
        const language_spoken = context.parameters.language;
        const country = agent.parameters.country;
        const duration = agent.parameters.duration;
        agent.add(`Wow! So cool you learned ${language_spoken} in ${country} for about ${duration.amount} ${duration.unit}!`);
    }

  intentMap.set('Language', languageHandler);
  intentMap.set('Language - custom', languageCustomHandler);
```

It works now, after making sure that the duration parameter value is either set to duration.original in the UI or after adding .amount and .unit to duration (otherwise you will get: "Wow! So cool you learned German in China for about [object Object]!" instead of "Wow! So cool you learned German in China for about 1 mo!

```
PARAMETER   VALUE
country China
duration    {"amount":1,"unit":"mo"}
```

Comment: I found these instructions that are supposedly taking care of my problem exactly: https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/integrate-services. I changed my code as indicated in the post and I am still not able to get what I need.

Comment: At a glance, your updated code should work. Can you update your question to clarify what you mean by "not able to get what I need"? What is happening or not happening when you try? Are there any errors?

Comment: The updated code kept not producing an answer with the entity from the previous turn, but I think it's because of the DF Online Editor being buggy. I ended up rewriting the code to be in line with the DF example and almost have it working now.  I am updating the answer above with the code that is directly in line with the DF post so that it's easier for people to spot eventual errors